# Cloudfare CDN cross-domain requests

Tags: http, cdn, cors, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

After looking the official docs at http://developers.cloudflare.com/ and searching cant find, yet, any documentation about the Cloudfare CDN service that allows to set or tweak CORS polices. I know amazon CDN service Cloudfront haves a way, any clues ?

> tweet from @codedit: https://twitter.com/codedit/statuses/193073220314861568

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is you won't be setting up/configuring CORS policies from CloudFlare.  You can have them in place via Amazon's S3 (a common setup we see) and then use CloudFlare in front of S3 and there won't be any issues or conflict there.

But in terms of CORS policies specifically at CloudFlare -- we don't offer that functionality at this time.